# I can't play games with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, games, acer

I erased the entire disk to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer Aspire 5750G.

I tried Heros of Newerth, Teeworlds, and Super Tux 2. None of these games can be initialized.  Can anyone help me?

I can provide more details if you need them.

Comment: Yes, please add more details.  Pick one of the games, and explain how you to try to start it, and what you see after that.

Answer (score 0):

Again, try installing the Proprietary Drivers for nVIDIA.

Search for "Jockey" in the Dash, then click Additional Drivers. Find the one that says "nVIDIA" in the title.

Click Activate. The games should work.